# Can I download crash reports from Crashlytics without uploading .dSYM?

Tags: macos, crashlytics, google-fabric, dsym

It was said in docs, that

> All .app dSYMs are marked as required. When Crashlytics fails to receive one of
>   these dSYMs we are unable to properly symbolicate crashes. Once a
>   required dSYM is uploaded, Crashlytics will reprocess all impacted
>   crashes for the last 7 days and you will see new issues appears in the
>   crash dashboard.

So Fabric has reports even without dSYM. My question is: Can I download reports and symbolicate them manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. We store the crashes for 7 days, but don't have a mechanism to deliver them in an unprocessed format.